# Touchpad stopped working ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, xorg, touchpad, synaptics

I know it seems like an easy fix, but I do swear to you that I've tried everything. The thing is: I was typing normally and suddenly the touchpad stopped working.

I switched to Win10 to see if it was a hardwaare problem, but there it works fine.

I did this to verify if it was recognized and it is:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3242-001                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Then I did

```
xinput enable 11
```

but it didn't do much, still not working.

Then I did

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

and the reinstalled it. Still nothing.

Good, I thought, let me check online something. I found some threads and I tried to switch from synaptics to libinput, but the result was that I didn't had the driver of the touchpad recognized and it didn't show up in the list of xinput.

So I thought that maybe was because there was no Xorg.conf.d in /etc/X11/ but only in /usr/share/X11/Xorg.conf.d, so I copied the folder in /etc/X11/. It didn't do anything.

btw the folder is:

```
(base) fecke@MiFecke:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ls
10-amdgpu.conf  10-radeon.conf    51-synaptics-quirks.conf  70-wacom.conf
10-quirks.conf  40-libinput.conf  70-synaptics.conf
```

I did change the order between the two, didn't solve the problem.

This is the log of Xorg.0.log  (It's a bit long, sorry for that)

```
    [    15.637] (--) Log file renamed from "/home/fecke/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-1648.log" to "/home/fecke/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"
[    15.638] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[    15.638] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    15.638] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-168-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    15.638] Current Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-71-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 02:19:47 UTC 2019 x86_64
[    15.638] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-71-generic ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    15.638] Build Date: 14 November 2019  06:20:00PM
[    15.638] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    15.638] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    15.638]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    15.638] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    15.638] (==) Log file: "/home/fecke/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Nov 16 20:34:29 2019
[    15.638] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    15.639] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    15.639] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    15.639] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    15.639] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    15.639] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    15.639] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    15.639] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    15.639] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    15.639] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[..][    16.170] (**) 2.4G Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    16.170] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for '2.4G Mouse'
[    16.228] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 26 paused 0
[    16.228] (**) 2.4G Mouse: always reports core events
[    16.228] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    16.228] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    16.230] (II) event4  - 2.4G Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    16.230] (II) event4  - 2.4G Mouse: device is a pointer
[    16.230] (II) event4  - 2.4G Mouse: device removed
[    16.230] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:1EA7:0064.0001/input/input4/event4"
[    16.230] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "2.4G Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[    16.230] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    16.230] (**) 2.4G Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    16.230] (**) 2.4G Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    16.231] (**) 2.4G Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    16.231] (II) event4  - 2.4G Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    16.231] (II) event4  - 2.4G Mouse: device is a pointer
[    16.232] (II) config/udev: Adding input device 2.4G Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    16.232] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.232] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.233] (II) config/udev: Adding input device XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U (/dev/input/event14)
[    16.233] (**) XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    16.233] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U'
[    16.235] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event14 13:78 fd 27 paused 0
[    16.235] (**) XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U: always reports core events
[    16.235] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event14"
[    16.235] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    16.236] (II) event14 - XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    16.236] (II) event14 - XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U: device is a keyboard
[    16.236] (II) event14 - XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U: device removed
[    16.236] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input14/event14"
[    16.236] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    16.236] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    16.236] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "it,us"
[    16.236] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    16.237] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_alt_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    16.238] (II) event14 - XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    16.238] (II) event14 - XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam: XiaoMi U: device is a keyboard
[    16.239] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Synaptics TM3242-001 (/dev/input/event13)
[    16.239] (**) Synaptics TM3242-001: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[    16.239] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    16.239] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    16.239] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.239]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.9.0
[    16.239]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    16.239]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    16.239] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'Synaptics TM3242-001'
[    16.240] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event13 13:77 fd 28 paused 0
[    16.241] (**) Synaptics TM3242-001: always reports core events
[    16.241] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event13"
[    16.241] (II) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: found clickpad property
[    16.241] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: x-axis range 0 - 2000 (res 20)
[    16.241] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: y-axis range 0 - 1174 (res 20)
[    16.241] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: pressure range 0 - 255
[    16.241] (II) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: device does not report finger width.
[    16.241] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: buttons: left double triple
[    16.241] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x7ea5
[    16.241] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: invalid finger width range.  defaulting to 0 - 15
[    16.241] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: touchpad found
[    16.241] (**) Synaptics TM3242-001: always reports core events
[    16.241] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-SYNA3105:00/0018:06CB:7EA5.0002/input/input7/event13"
[    16.241] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Synaptics TM3242-001" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[    16.241] (**) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    16.241] (**) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    16.241] (**) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.086
[    16.242] (**) Synaptics TM3242-001: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    16.242] (**) Synaptics TM3242-001: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[    16.242] (**) Synaptics TM3242-001: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    16.242] (**) Synaptics TM3242-001: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    16.242] (--) synaptics: Synaptics TM3242-001: touchpad found
[    16.243] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Synaptics TM3242-001 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    16.243] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.243] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.244] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Intel HID events (/dev/input/event5)
[    16.244] (**) Intel HID events: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    16.244] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Intel HID events'
[    16.245] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 29 paused 0
[    16.245] (**) Intel HID events: always reports core events
[    16.245] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    16.245] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    16.246] (II) event5  - Intel HID events: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    16.246] (II) event5  - Intel HID events: device is a keyboard
[    16.246] (II) event5  - Intel HID events: device removed
[    16.246] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/INT33D5:00/input/input5/event5"
[    16.246] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Intel HID events" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    16.246] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    16.246] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "it,us"
[    16.246] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    16.246] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_alt_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    16.247] (II) event5  - Intel HID events: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    16.247] (II) event5  - Intel HID events: device is a keyboard
[    16.248] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event9)
[    16.248] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.248] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.248] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event10)
[    16.248] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.248] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.249] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event11)
[    16.249] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.249] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.249] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event12)
[    16.250] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.250] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.250] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event7)
[    16.250] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.250] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.251] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event8)
[    16.251] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.251] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.251] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[    16.251] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    16.251] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    16.252] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 30 paused 0
[    16.252] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    16.252] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    16.252] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    16.253] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    16.253] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    16.253] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[    16.253] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[    16.253] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[    16.253] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    16.253] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "it,us"
[    16.253] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    16.253] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_alt_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    16.254] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    16.254] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    16.611] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1681
[    16.611] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    16.611] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  140.25  1920 1968 2000 2125  1080 1083 1089 1100 +hsync -vsync (66.0 kHz eP)
```

This is 70-synaptics.conf

```
 Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "SHMConfig" "on"
EndSection
```

This is 40-libinput.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

I really don't have a single clue on where is the problem. Why it stopped working. I've tried literally everything. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]
Updating the kernel (From v4.x.x to v5.x.x) did the work! awesome

Comment: Though an unsatisfying solution, this worked for me too. Here's an article about how to install a newer official kernel on old Ubuntu 18.04 installations: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-hwe-kernel/